# How to hook a function from the same process and get the address of the caller function?

Tags: c++, hook, function-pointers

I need to do it to avoid calling a function of my process from injected code.

so would like to hook this function to check whether the call is from the current module or it is from an external module, then I compare the address of the instruction who did the call with the module address range.

Thanks

Comment: You can't do this in standard C++. You'll need to specify a platform.

Comment: I dont understand why I cant in standard C++!! I think there are some APIs that allow function hooks and maybe giving some info about stack

Comment: if I have to use some additional libraries, so it should be free and stable library
thanks,

Comment: Standard C++ has no concept of a stack.

Comment: So, is there any solution to controle the caller function address range? I have to detect if I get a call from external function.

Answer (score 0):

MSVC has an intrinsic _ReturnAddress, this give the return address of function's caller,
so you can call this in the very beginning of protected function and compare it with specified module (base, length) to detect whether it's allowed to execute left part of the function.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
In the case of when I hook a function and my hook callback is called after calling the hooked function, what this function will return in callback function? is it the address of the hooked function or the caller
I couldnt test because I still dont know how to hook a function.
Thanks